# Adding badge to calendar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<Dialog open={openModal} onClose={handleModalClose}>
            <DialogTitle>
              {selectedData &&
                `${selectedData.firstName} ${selectedData.lastName}'s Calendar`}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <DateCalendar
                readOnly
                views={["day"]}
                disableFuture
                sx={{ width: "max-content" }}
                renderLoading={() => <DayCalendarSkeleton />}
                value={value}
                onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
                slotProps={{  }}
              />
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={handleModalClose} color="primary">
                Close
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
```

when I want to add slotProps or slots inside  the content was blank after I clicked the Button

I want to add slotProps or slots.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the docs? Here is an example: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-calendar/#system-DateCalendarServerRequest.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import Badge from "@mui/material/Badge";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { PickersDay } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/PickersDay";
import { DateCalendar } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DateCalendar";
import { DayCalendarSkeleton } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DayCalendarSkeleton";

const initialValue = dayjs("2022-04-17");

function ServerDay(props) {
  const { highlightedDays = [], day, outsideCurrentMonth, ...other } = props;

  const isSelected =
    !props.outsideCurrentMonth &&
    highlightedDays.indexOf(props.day.date()) >= 0;

  return (
    <Badge
      key={props.day.toString()}
      overlap="circular"
      badgeContent={isSelected ? "" : undefined}
    >
      <PickersDay
        {...other}
        outsideCurrentMonth={outsideCurrentMonth}
        day={day}
      />
    </Badge>
  );
}

export default function DateCalendarServerRequest() {
  const requestAbortController = React.useRef(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [highlightedDays, setHighlightedDays] = React.useState([1, 2, 15]);

  const handleMonthChange = (date) => {
    if (requestAbortController.current) {
      // make sure that you are aborting useless requests
      // because it is possible to switch between months pretty quickly
      requestAbortController.current.abort();
    }
    setIsLoading(true);
    setHighlightedDays([]);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DateCalendar
        defaultValue={initialValue}
        loading={isLoading}
        onMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
        renderLoading={() => <DayCalendarSkeleton />}
        slots={{
          day: ServerDay,
        }}
        slotProps={{
          day: {
            highlightedDays,
          },
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```